# What could be wrong with this code? variable is not passing between the pages. trying to retrieve image from db

Tags: php, image

here are two files,

LIST IMAGE:

```
<?php

    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("wordgraphic");
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM userdata ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1,1";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

?>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>List BLOB Images</TITLE>
<link href="imageStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<?php
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); 
    echo $row['id'];
    ?>
        <img src="imageView.php?image_id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" /><br/>

<?php       

    mysql_close($conn);
?>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

And other file:

```
<?php

    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("wordgraphic") or die(mysql_error());
    if(isset($_GET['id']))
    {
        $sql = "SELECT imageType,image FROM userdata WHERE id=" . $_GET['id'];
        $result = mysql_query("$sql") or die("<b>Error:</b> Problem on Retrieving Image BLOB<br/>" . mysql_error());
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        header("Content-type: " . $row["imageType"]);
        echo $row["image"];
    }
    else
        "error";
    mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

The second file is showing an image if i provide a static id but variable is not passed among the page and second issue is that when i echo :

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM userdata ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1,1";
        $result=mysql_query($sql);
```

It is giving id of not the last inserted query but 2nd Last inserted query.
Please help !

Comment: On the first page you are calling the second page with this imageView.php?image_id= and in the second file you are trying to get the id with $_GET['id'] - You are "getting" on the wrong name. - Oh and mysql is deprecated, you should use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: Please don't shout your question at us. The caps are completely unnecessary.

Comment: and your query execution isn't right...  it should be `mysql_query($sql)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first problem change

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
```

to:

```
if(isset($_GET['image_id']))
```

and for second problem

edit your query likr this :

```
SELECT id FROM userdata ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

or
    SELECT id FROM userdata ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1

Comment: Thank you so much Mr go, id and image_id was my mistake and about the select id clause is used mysql_insert_id() its working fine,,, Thank you again

Comment: @AzraMahrukh : if your problem is solved then please marked my ans as right, so i can get points and ask some my doubts here

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT id FROM userdata ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`

omit the coma and 1 on the last part of your query.

or if you want you can do this.

`SELECT id FROM userdata ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1`